# getting a class from a string haxe

Tags: types, haxe

I'm working on parsing in entities as xml, and I've run into a problem: my engine uses components, and I'd like to be able to add components in my xml as well, in a structure like this:

```
<entity tag="player" x="0" y="0">
    <art width="32" height="32" path="some/path/here">
        <animation name="idle" frames="0,1,2" framerate="10" looped="true" />
    </art>
    <component type="MovementComponent">
        <param name="speed" value="10"/>
    </component>
</entity>
```

(the part up until component parsing is all done:))

so I thought: every component can implement a static `build(parameters:Map):TypeOfComponent` function, and do what it wants with the values, easy enough right? but, how do I get the component class from the string identifier, is there a haxe function to do this? I just need the class, so I can call the static build() function, does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks,
Nico

Comment: oh, just found Type.resolveClass(), this might be it, leaving this open while I test it

Comment: You're in the right track. Use `Type.createInstance(Type.resolveClass(name),[constructor, args])`. Answer you're own question once you've solved it so we can vote for it :)

Comment: but then wouldn't I need the proper types for my arguments? I was hoping I could just pass a map of strings and let the component's logic sort out what types it wants from it...Any way to do that? currently I'm trying to call a static function on what is returned from Type.resolveClass, but the compiler is failing:( thanks for your help!:)

Comment: I guess I could allow no parameters in the constructor of the component, and then call a **non-static** `build()` function, but I'd rather keep the constructors with mandatory parameters, then the **static** `build()` function could sort out the parameters, call the constructor, and return the result, is this possible?

Comment: To get the type info of the params of an constructor, you will have to use http://haxe.org/doc/advanced/rtti?lang=en or manually use macros + metadata to store the info in some way.

Comment: I think I'll just add an extra "type" parameter to the XML, and use that to parse the data, that way it's up to the user:)

Comment: Please, add selfanswer, so the question will not hang in unanswered group. It is perfectly ok to answer your own questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: I know:) I was planning to dont worry, but I'm not home, and I'd like to finish the code and then make a nice clean answer:)

Comment: @jason I answered my question, thanks for the help:)

Answer (score 2):

So here's how I solved it, with help from Jason O'Neil in the comments above. I force a "type" attribute to be supplied in the parameter element: `<param name="speed" type="int" value="10"/>`, and use those to cast all the values to their proper types. I then put each parameter into an Array and use:

```
var classType = Type.resolveClass(component.get("type"));
var newComponent = Type.createInstance(classType, params);
```

To build the component from the information contained in the xml.

Just to be clear, here my final xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<data>
<entity tag="player" x="0" y="0">
    <art width="32" height="32" path="assets/images/test.png">
        <animation name="idle" frames="0,1,2" framerate="10" looped="true" />
    </art>
    <component type="MComponent">
        <param name="speed" type="int" value="10"/>
    </component>
</entity>
</data>
```

The most confusing problem I came across was the need to reference the component somewhere in code, so it gets compiled, very simple to do `import MyComponent;` anywhere in your code, but it wasn't something that I did instinctively. Otherwise, the component does not get compiled, and cannot be instantiated.

Thanks for your help, and I hope maybe this helps someone else:),

Nico

Ohh, and hey, if anyone want's to check out my entity-framework, its available here (with all new xml parsing;)): https://github.com/NicoM1/IceEntity

Comment: Glad you were able to find a solution :)